# How to stop Excel 97 from prompting that file was created with a later version

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet that was initially created with Excel 2007. However, Excel 97 is used regularly to edit this document and the annoyance is that Excel always prompts before saving:

> The file was created using a later version of Microsoft Excel. If you
>   save this file using Microsoft Excel 97, information created with
>   features in the later version may be lost.

OK... I continue with the save. But it prompts again the next time I save. I would have hoped that this information would have been overwritten when I save the document, but it is not.

How can I prevent this dialog popping up every time I save this document, without recreating the document in the old version of Excel?

Comment: @pnuts: Are you referring to the file format... BIFF8 for Excel 97 - is that what that code outputs? Although if I have already saved it from Excel 97 then the file format has presumably been overwritten although there is still a flag in the file that indicates that a later version created it. I have had a quick look at the file using a hex editor, but I don't currently know enough about the file format to make any changes!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try setting a before save macro that would disable that warning? something like

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
  application.displayalerts=false
  activeworkbook.save
  application.displayalerts=true
  cancel=true
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although this doesn't work unfortunately. The warning prompt appears _before_ the BeforeSave event fires.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think to solve this is to open the file in Excel 2007 and do a `Save as`, choosing the `Excel 97-2003 Workbook` format. Then you should be able to use it with Excel 97 without the warning.

[image]

Comment: No, it is not recreating, it is simply saving it in an older version Excel.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the described problem too. I even searched in all dll's of Excel 97 - without success.
The only way to solve the problem is connected with many manually work.

If you want to take that on yourself do the following:

Create an new Excel 97 workbook.
Also open your workbook with the message "The file was created using a later version of Microsoft Excel ........".
And now the manually work begins.

Copy the contents of every sheet, sheet by sheet into in the same-named sheets of the new created Excel 97 workbook.
At last you have to copy all VBA macros into the new one. 
Finished!
Ready! 
I wish you great success.
Dr. Peter Schoop, Germany

Answer (score 1):

The manual work that Dr. Schoop describes may be significantly reduced:

Right-click on the 1st sheet tab
"Select all sheets"
"Move or Copy" (checking "Create a copy")

The VBA macros still have to be copied manually.